# Does HSQLDB have extensions like PostgreSQL?

Tags: hsqldb

PostgreSQL - `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;`

HSQLDB - ?

How do we get around this problem?

Comment: No, it does not have any "packaging" concept like extensions in Postgres

Comment: Is there a workaround

Comment: For which problem? You can create stored procedures and functions in HSQLDB. What problem are you trying to solve by putting them into an extension? Maybe you want to look in to tools like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) or Flyway.

Comment: There is absolutely no way you can run a `pg_dump` script against HSQLDB. `create extension` is only the tip of the iceberg

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If is so incompatible with HSQLDB, what is the purpose of having POSTGRES mode at all?

Answer (score 0):

> User-defined Java stored procedures and functions, including aggregate functions ~ http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html

From their website it appears that it supports stored procedures. However it appears that it doesn't offer any other kind of extension support.

Comment: An extension in Postgres is more then just "stored procedures".